# Linking Freestyle to Camera DOF

Tags: camera, freestyle, depth-of-field

I was wondering if it is possible to use Freestyle in conjunction with the camera’s DOF? I would like to set up a wide angle camera with focus on a far away subject, and have the freestyle lines overlay the areas of the image that have been blurred by DOF. Almost like a linear gradient of freestyle, being strongest closer to the camera and fading out towards the subject.